# SQLServer : Grouping and Replacing a COLUMN value with the DATA from other table, without UDF

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to replace the numbers in @CommentsTable column "Comments" with the equivalent text from @ModTable table, without using UDF in a single SELECT. May with a CTE. Tried STUFF with REPLACE, but no luck.

Any suggestions would be a great help!

Sample:

```
DECLARE @ModTable TABLE
(  
    ID INT,  
    ModName VARCHAR(10),  
    ModPos VARCHAR(10) 
)

DECLARE @CommentsTable TABLE
(  
    ID INT,  
    Comments VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @CommentsTable  
VALUES  (1, 'MyFirst 5 Comments with 6'),
        (2, 'MySecond comments'),
        (3, 'MyThird comments 5')

INSERT INTO @ModTABLE  
VALUES  (1, '[FIVE]', '5'),
        (1, '[SIX]', '6'),
        (1, '[ONE]', '1'),
        (1, '[TWO]', '2')

SELECT T1.ID, <<REPLACED COMMENTS>>     
FROM @CommentsTable T1  
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.Comments


**Expected Result:**
ID Comments               
1  MyFirst [FIVE] Comments with [SIX]
2  MySecond comments
3  MyThird comments [FIVE]
```

Comment: Table valued function and scalar both are out of the question?

Comment: are you ok with inserting into some temp table prior to operation

Comment: Your replaces are likely to be sensitive to the order of application. What happens one you get into two-digit numbers?

Comment: @TheGameiswar Sure. Please try your solution with Temp Table.

Comment: @shawnt00 FYI, luckily I've the range 1...9 only now.

Comment: Thanks @Becuzz for the edit.

Comment: Yes, @SQLChao Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=> CLR Function()

As I have lot of records in "CommentsTable" and the "ModTable" would have multiple ModName for each comments, finally decided to go with CLR Function. Thanks all of you for the suggestions and pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a cursor, span over the `@ModTable` and do each replacement a time

```
DECLARE replcursor FOR SELECT ModPos, ModName FROM @ModTable;
OPEN replcursor;

DECLARE modpos varchar(100) DEFAULT "";
DECLARE modname varchar(100) DEFAULT "";

get_loop: LOOP
    FETCH replcursor INTO @modpos, @modname

    SELECT T1.ID, REPLACE(T1.Comments, @modpos, @modname)     
    FROM @CommentsTable T1  
    GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.Comments
END LOOP get_loop;
```

Of course, you can store the results in a temp table and get the results altogether in the end of loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop to iterate over the records and the mods.  I slightly modified your @ModTable to have unique values for ID.  If this is not your data structure, then you can use a window function like ROW_NUMBER() to get a unique value over which you can iterate.

Revised script example:

```
  DECLARE @ModTable TABLE
 (  
    ID INT,  
    ModName VARCHAR(10),  
    ModPos VARCHAR(10) 
  )

   DECLARE @CommentsTable TABLE
(  
    ID INT,  
    Comments VARCHAR(100)
)


   INSERT INTO @CommentsTable  
VALUES  (1, 'MyFirst 5 Comments with 6'),
        (2, 'MySecond comments'),
        (3, 'MyThird comments 5')

   INSERT INTO @ModTABLE  
VALUES  (1, '[FIVE]', '5'),
        (2, '[SIX]', '6'),
        (3, '[ONE]', '1'),
        (4, '[TWO]', '2')


declare @revisedTable table (id int, comments varchar(100))
declare @modcount int = (select count(*) from @ModTable)
declare @commentcount int = (select count(*) from @CommentsTable)
declare @currentcomment varchar(100) = ''
while @commentcount > 0
    begin
        set @modcount = (select count(*) from @ModTable)
        set @currentcomment = (select Comments from @CommentsTable where ID = @commentcount)
        while @modcount > 0
            begin
                set @currentcomment = REPLACE(  @currentcomment, 
                                                (SELECT TOP 1 ModPos FROM @ModTable WHERE ID = @modcount), 
                                                (SELECT TOP 1 ModName FROM @ModTable WHERE ID = @modcount))
                set @modcount = @modcount - 1
            end
        INSERT INTO @revisedTable (id, comments) 
        SELECT @commentcount, @currentcomment
        set @commentcount = @commentcount - 1
    end

SELECT *
FROM @revisedTable
order by id
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Hope WHILE is better than CURSOR implementation from Omar Alves !? Working myself.... and will wait for some more suggestions. Please bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the will work even though I generally avoid recursive queries. It assumes that you have consecutive ids though:

```
with Comments as
( 
    select ID, Comments, 0 as ConnectID
    from @CommentsTable
    union all
    select ID, replace(c.Comments, m.ModPos, m.ModName), m.ConnectID
    from Comments c inner join @ModTable m on m.ConnectID = c.ConnectID + 1
) 
select * from Comments
where ConnectID = (select max(ID) from @ModTable)
```